# How does one extend the notion of infimum to Metric Spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, definition, supremum-and-infimum

In particular I was trying to make sense of the expression:

$$ dist(V,f) = \inf_{v \in V} \| v - f \|_{\mathcal M}$$

which seems to require me to extend the notion of infimum to metric spaces and things that look like minimization problems.

To start this search I reviewed the definition of infimum from Walter Rudin's book (here paraphrased):

Suppose $(P, \leq)$ is an ordered set, $S \subset P$ and $S$ is bounded from bellow. Suppose there exists an $\alpha \in P$ with the following properties:

1. $\alpha$ is a lower bound. i.e. $\forall x \in S, \alpha \leq x$. i.e. $\alpha \in LowerBounds(S)$
2. If $\gamma > \alpha$ then $\gamma \in P$ is not a lower bound. i.e. if  $\gamma > \alpha \implies \gamma \notin LowerBounds(S)$.

which makes sense and the notation:

$$ \alpha = \inf S$$

makes sense to me. Similarly I think:

$$ \alpha = \inf_{ x \in P} S $$

makes sense to me too, just being more explicit over which set (i.e. $P$) is the infimum and with respect to what set (i.e. $S$) we are taking the infimum.

However, I am having difficulties extending this notation because in a metric space we don't explicitly have an ordered set nor do we have the explicit sets $P$ and $S$ defined.

It seems that for this to make sense or be equivalent we would have to define $P = \mathbb R$ the reals and $S_f = \{ \| v - f \|_{\mathcal M} : f \in V\}$ which seems in this case that $S_f \subset \mathbb R$ and the ordered set is induced by the standard order on the number line. The issue in this case might be that multiple **different** $v \in V$ could map to the same real number depending on the nature of $V$. So in this case it seems that the infimum would be the smallest numerical/real value for $\| v - f \|_{\mathcal M}$ and that specific number is unique but it seems multiple different $v \in V$ could achieve it (at least in principle). So the value achieving the infimum seems to not be unique.

However, something else worries me. It worries me that each value of $v \in V$ decreases $\| v - f \|_{\mathcal M}$ a little bit more and more, making it a sequence that decreases forever and that approaches some value (say $L_{B_f}$). If this is true it seems that the infimum wouldn't exist, at least not using element from $V$, right? Would I have to change $V$ in this case? Do I really need the word infimum if its not achievable? I know that sometimes one cannot achieve the minimum so we use the word infimum. Is this one of those examples?

To make it clear my main worries are two:

1. What the role of $\| v - f\|_{\mathcal M}$ and $V$ is. It seems that $\| v - f\|_{\mathcal M}$ is just for us to define the set we are looking to define a lower bound and that $V$ is just an index set.
2. It seems that infimum has a small assumption that I just realized (that isn't clear until you "view it" as an optimization problem. In this case $\alpha = \inf S \iff  \alpha = \inf_{ x \in P} S $ which is important to make explicit what "the minimization is over". It seems that the minimization is always over the set $P$ i.e. the larger set that $S$ is a susbet of. But if the minimization was over something else that did not have say, a largest element itself and we had: $ \inf_{x \in Q} S$ where we are looking to lower bound $S$ with $Q$ but $Q$ itself might a subset of $P$ **but** not have a largest element. In this case the "infimum" would not be defined. Maybe this is not what the definition of infimum is and it should be that we look for a lowest value that actually exists. Otherwise, there is largest lower bound...right?

Comment: Should that be a capital v?  Ie $dist (V,f)=\inf_{v\in V}||v-f||$?  If so this means: S={||v-f||: v in V} is a set of non-negative real numbers.  As such it has an inf.  dist (V,f) is the lower bound of all these distances.  One can think of it as the shortest distance from point f to the set V.  Except it may be a limit of the shortest distances to points and the might not be any point that actual distance.

Comment: You use the word infimum  (rather than minimum) precisely be cause it may not be achieved.  Let V={(x,y)|x^2+y^2 < 1}.  Let f = (1,0).  f is not in V so for any v inV, ||v-f|| > 0.  But for any r > 0 we can find a v in V so that ||v-f|| < r.  So inf||v - f|| = 0.  That is the greatest lower bound of distances from f to points of V.

Comment: @fleablood I think what it boils down to is that the notation $ \inf_{v \in V} \| v - f \| $ is really confusing to me because I think what it actually means is $\inf \{ \| v - f\| : v \in V \}$. i.e. we are looking for the infimum of the set $ \{ \| v - f\| : v \in V \}$ which depending on $V$ it could be zero or something else. What I initially thought is that we are looking for the value of $v$ that achieves the infimum, but of course that doesn't exist, because the infimum might not be achieved.

Comment: @fleablood It seems that using that notation as an optimization problem makes it really confusing to me because I somehow implicitly thought of it abstractly as "a way" to find $v$. In other words, we are looking over $v \in V$ to find the infimum, but by the definition of infimum that doesn't make sense. What it has to mean is something else like $inf \{ \| v-f \| : v \in V \}$. i.e. the infimum of some set. Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: I think you have it now.  I personally think of it as "how far is f from the set V".  "Well, which point?" "The nearest one?"  "Well there is no nearest one; in fact it is an open set, for any point we can always found another point closer to the edge and closer to f"  "okay, so if we start at f take the shortest path toward V, what is the shortest distance to get to either a point of V or the edge of V?"  "Okay, that's inf|f-v|..."

Comment: Imagine if V has a "fuzzy border"  then one can get up to border but there is no "first point" of V.  In one dimension let f=-1 and V=(0,1).  All points in V or more than 1 away from f, but greatest Lowe bounds of the distances is 1.  So "the distance from -1 to V is 1" is meaningful and true but the is no v in (0,1) where the distance *is* 1.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to be concerned about the metric space at all. The metric space only serves as the index set for the collection of real numbers $||  v-f||_{\mathcal{M}}$.

Comment: I think what worried me the most now that I reflect on my question is that when we take an infimum it seems that there is some other set that helps us bound from bellow the "real" set we are interested in i.e. $S$. So I guess my worry was, what if the infimum is not actually defined, as in $inf_{ x \in Q } S$ where $Q, S \subset P$. For example. $S = \{ \frac{1}{n} \}$ and $Q = \{ - \frac{1}{n} \}$. In this case it seems that we can't actually get a greatest lower bound because $Q$ keeps approaching 0. It seems that the infimum is always with respect to the set $S$ is a subset of, i.e. $P$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the notation.
The infimum is defined as the largest lower bound of an ordered set (in your example $P$), usually a subset of the real numbers. It always exists if $P$ is not empty (possibly it is -$\infty$).

The expression

> $\alpha = \inf_{x\in P} S$

does not make sense.
In general yo use the notation $\inf S$. However, if the set $S$ is given by the image of some function $f:X \to\mathbb{R}$, it is convenient to write 
$$\inf_{x \in X} f(x),$$ which stands for $$\inf \{f(x)|~{x \in X}\}=\inf f(X).$$

EDIT: I dont have enough reputation to comment, so i write it here...

I didn't write any definition, so i am not quite sure what you are refering to.
There are some equivalent definitions of the infimum, one of them is, that the infimum of $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$.
It always exists, because $-\infty$ is a lower bound to every non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$. And as there exists a lower bound, there also exists a greatest lower bound. Note that this does not mean that $-\infty\in S$ (which doesn't make sense anyway).

Comment: why does the infimum always has to exist? Is it just because $inf_{x \in Q} S$ isn't a real mathematical expression? I thought of defining that just to mean find some element in $x \in Q$ that is the greatest lower bound of $S$. It seems for some reason that isn't what the definition of infimum is. Is that correct? Btw, the notation that you explicitly wrote makes sense to me. It seems thats what the real definition of infimum is. Right?

Comment: The real numbers, by definition, have the least upper bound/greatest lower bound property.  Every non-empty set that is bounded below (Q is not bounded below) has an inf.  {|| f-v||: v in V} is a set of non negative real numbers.  Each one is at least 0.  So the are bounded below by 0.  So inf exist.  Even though there could be no such w where |w-f|=inf||v-f;v in V||.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X $ be a metric space with $||x-y|| ;x,y\in X $ being the notation for the metric "distance" between $x $ and $y $.

Let $V\subset X $.  Let $f\in X $.  $f $ may or may not be in $V $ but in general we should assume it doesn't.

Let $S \subset R ; S =\{||f-v||:v \in V\} $.  In other words, $S $ is the set of distances from $f $ to the various points of $V $.  Now for any $d\in S $, $d \ge 0$ and if $f \not \in V $ then $d=||f-v||$ for some $v \in V $ so $d > 0$.

So $S $ is bounded below by $0$.  So assuming $V $ is non empty, $S $ is non empty so $\inf S $ exists and $\inf S \ge 0$.

Define $dist(f,V) =\inf S$.  Notationwise, as this value depends on $f $ and the set $V $ we can notate this as $dist (f,V)= \inf_{v\in V}||f-v||=\inf\{||f-v||:v\in V\} $.

Now it may be possible if $f \not\in V $, that for all $v \in V $ that $||f-v|| > dist(f,V) $.  In other words there is no single nearest point of $V $ to $f $. It's possible if $f $ is a limit point not in $V $ that $dist (f,V)=0$.

But if $f $ is not in $V $ and $f $ is not a limit point of $V $ then there is an $r>0$ so that $B (f,r) $ has no point of $V $ so for all $v \in V$, $||f-v|| \ge r $ so $dist(f,V)  \ge r > 0$.